# I am getting a e/cl error in android studio and need help solving it

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working in android studio and keep getting this error on run

```
E/CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Primitive.shaderb'
    [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Default.shaderb'
    [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'spot_light_glow.rgba4.tex'
E/CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'light_flare.rgba4.tex'
A/CL_magma: [FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8730 (Thread-440)
```

I am unsure of how to fix this - can anyone help